# Low request throughput in Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've been using the google analytics API to authenticate on behalf of my customers and show them customized reports. The req throughput was always good enough (11 req/sec).

However, since a couple of days ago, the throughput had decreased drastically, from 11 req/sec to 5 req/sec. And the reports that usually took 10 seconds, now finishes in 40 seconds.

Nothing has been modified in the last days, neither the queries nor the way to access the API

I tried but haven't found anything about any performance degradation from Google.

**Here are the requests for the last 4 days:**

[image]

Is there something that I can do to validate what's wrong or where is the problem?

Comment: Create it as an issue and i will ping the team for you https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400  Something was released last week for quotas but it shouldnt have caused this.   Its worth informing them